# Windows printer doesn't show up, how to remove driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer, network-printer

I have a networked windows printer that I first tried to install in windows 7 with a 64bit driver wich was wrong, now the printer always results in an error
trying to install it 0x00000c1 more or less zeros.

I don't see the printer installed and can't find it anywhere.
How can I remove the drivers (assuming that the problem are those drivers).

**EDITED**

Connection from other computers works, the directory %windir%\System32\spool\ has litle information about what printer the driver is and windows stops me from deleting everything.%windir%\System32\spool\printers is empty.

Every time I try to install the printer I get the same error.

Comment: Locate the physical driver file and delete it from your local system.

Comment: Andy knows this is an option, he said it in the question. He does not know *HOW* to do that though @Ramhound. / Sherlock

Comment: @JoshStevenson - Please be polite to other users.  The reason I didn't go into detail is because the first result on the search "how to delete printer driver" was multiple results that explain in detail "what, where, and how" to delete a printer's driver.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do with most things printer related is **always** restart the print spooler! It falls over so much.

Go into services ( Win key + R, "`services.msc`" )
Restart the print spooler, then refresh the printers window, see if it shows up again.

---

The location of your printer drivers can be found, along with all the other printer information, here `C:\Windows\System32\spool\`

( *Where `C:` is the drive you installed Windows on, if you have not installed it on the default drive you can locate it using `%windir%\System32\spool\`* )

Drivers are inside the folder `Drivers`

---

I do however suggest checking sometihng first. As it is a networked printer I am going to assume that it is shared. get the `hostname` of the computer / server that it is physically connected to ( *that is of course if it isn't fully wireless* ) and browse to it via `\\hostname`, if the printer is shared you will see it there.

---

Another method would be to manually conntect to the printer using it's IP Address. Get this by printing a diagnostic page from the printer ( *will be instructions in it's manual, or google* ) you will have to manually provide the driver for it also this way but judging from your question I'm going to assume you already know how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for following :

1. Disable Firewall for test reasons on this system
2. See if you can ping this network printer (if at this printer supports ping)
3. Try changing NIC speed on both ends to 10 Mbps

At this point I just hope this computer is free of malaware/viruses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version of Windows with the Print Management console you can view all the print drivers installed on a computer. Hit the start menu button and search "Print Management" to see if it's available. If you find Print Management on a different Windows 7 machine, use that machine to see the drivers of any networked machine by adding its hostname as a print server. A quick overview with pictures can be found [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/geek-way-managing-printers-print-management-console).